# Running PowerPoint Viewer from commandline on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, registry, electron, powerpoint

I'm running PowerPoint Presentations from my desktop app, which is written in the electron (node.js). I use child_process to run powerpnt.exe with params, and it works fine. I'm looking for similar solution for workstations, where only PowerPoint Viewer is installed. On some machines, pptview.exe was working fine, but this not always works, I need a reliable solution. I tried to find out the full PowerPoint Viewer path in Windows registry, but I'm not sure where should I look for. Maybe someone knows the reliable way to run pptx file from nodejs in PowerPoint Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

The default location for PowerPoint viewer is:

- 32 bit Windows 7: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\pptview.exe
- 64 bit Windows 7: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\pptview.exe

I would start by checking if those files exists. If not you could check the registry. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry holds information on which application should open which file. You should find something like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\`.

If all else fails you could try to do a silent installation of PowerPoint viewer in the background. Download the installation file in the background and run it with `PowerPointViewer.exe /quiet /passive /norestart`. More info [here](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/software-installation/silent_install_Microsoft-PowerPoint-Viewer-2010.html).

Comment: Is /Office12/ constant or can it change? 

I already detect from if PPT viewer is installed, but i can't find any path there.